# How can I get Netlogo turtle coordinates which can then be used by the other turtles to navigate them to that turtle?

Tags: netlogo

In netlogo, I have four turtles, one Pacman turtle and 3 ghosts which will attempt to track the Pacman down by using its location that should be reported inside a variable, but I can't understand how to retrieve the Pacman turtle's location and store it in a variable. This variable should be updated with every move the Pacman makes so that the ghosts are attracted to the newest patch location where the Pacman was.

Update: I have used the patch-here command to retrieve the location of the pacman and store it in a global variable called "PacManLocation". Is this correct and if so how can I get my ghost's turtles to go to that specific patch one step at a time? I've tried the forward command writing "forward PacManLocation" but I get an error saying that it expected a numerical input.

Here is the original code:

```
to PlayGame
    ask ghostsOne [
        face min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = blue ] [ distance PacManLocation ] forward 0.7
    ]
    ask ghostsTwo [
        face min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = blue ] [ distance PacManLocation ] forward 0.7
    ]
    ask ghostsThree [
        face min-one-of patches with [ pcolor = blue ] [ distance PacManLocation ] forward 0.7
    ]
end
```

Comment: I have used the patch-here command to retrieve the location of the pacman and store it in a global variable called "PacManLocation". Is this correct and if so how can i get my ghosts turtles to go to that specific patch one step at a time? I've tried the forward command writing "forward PacManLocation" but i get an error saying that it expected a numerical input.

Comment: Add the code you tried in your question, it will be easier. Don't hesitate to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ;)

Comment: It's best not to put code in a comment; as you can, it becomes very hard to read. Stack Overflow lets you revise questions. Revise your question to include the code.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started. (Not tested.)

```
to PlayGame
  ;;it is better to make a ghosts breed or at least use a global,
  ;;but here we stick with what you have
  let ghosts (turtle-set ghostsOne ghostsTwo ghostsThree)
  ask ghosts [move]
end

to move
  if (blue != [pcolor] of patch-ahead 0.7) [
    face min-one-of neighbors with [pcolor = blue] [distance PacManLocation]
  ]
  fd 0.7
end
```